# Merging two different scripts in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, html, github, three.js, gltf

I am trying to produce a shadow map that works with the sun API in THREE.JS
[URL-1](https://github.com/antarktikali/threejs-sunlight)
I want to use the work in the link as a SUN API. The code works fine and the result looks like in the first picture.
[SUN-API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIfMv.png)

I have also another code where I import a 3D model in GLTF format. This code also works on its own but I can't combine the two because they use different threejs scripts. [GLTF-Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mid8Q.png)

For example, first Github code use three.js file which was manually edited.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>Three.js Sun Light Demo</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="./lib/three.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="SunLight.js"></script>
        <script src="sunscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The second code to import the 3D model,it use three.module.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - GLTFloader + compressed</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Import maps polyfill -->
        <!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
        <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';

            import { RoomEnvironment } from 'three/addons/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';
            import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
            import { ShadowMesh } from 'three/addons/objects/ShadowMesh.js';
    
            


            let camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;

            init();
            render();

            function init() {

                const container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                
                //camera

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.set( 20, 100, 0 );

                
                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xbbbbbb );
            
                
                // ground 

                

                const plane = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000 ),
                    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x99ff99 } )
                );
                plane.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                plane.position.y = - 0.5;
                scene.add( plane );

                

                plane.receiveShadow = true;
                //plane.castShadow = true;


                const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'models/gltf/' );
                loader.load( 'building_3.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
                    gltf.scene.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                    gltf.castShadow = true;
                    gltf.receiveShadow = false;
                    scene.add( gltf.scene );
                    render();
                } );

                // light

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333));

                //addShadowedLight( 50, 30, 1, 0xffffff, 2 );
                addShadowedLight( 0.5, 1, - 1, 0xffffff, 1 );

        


                //renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                
                

                const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
                controls.minDistance = 400;
                controls.maxDistance = 1500;
                controls.target.set( 10, 90, - 16 );
                controls.update();

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                render();

            }

            function addShadowedLight( x, y, z, color, intensity ) {

                const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( color, intensity );
                directionalLight.position.set( x, y, z );
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                directionalLight.castShadow = true;

                const d = 5000;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;

                directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 4;

                directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
                directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

                //irectionalLight.shadow.bias = - 0.001;

            }

            //

            function render() {


                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Since I don't have much experience with threejs, I can't move forward at the moment. I tried to bring the two codes together but I get different errors every time I try.

In the simplest way, when I put the second script into the first html file, I don't get any error because I leave both codes as they are.

```
<script src="./lib/three.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="SunLight.js"></script>
        <script src="sunscript.js"></script>
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';

            import { RoomEnvironment } from 'three/addons/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';
            import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
            import { ShadowMesh } from 'three/addons/objects/ShadowMesh.js';
```

But the result is two models displayed one below the other in an html file.

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq8ob.png)

The only thing I want to do now is to merge the GLTF 3D model at the bottom with the SUN API code. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: That sunlight script you're using is 7 years old, and [is using `Three.js r78`](https://github.com/antarktikali/threejs-sunlight/blob/master/lib/three.js). The current revision is `r149`, so you're bound to run into many compatibility issues beyond this one. I recommend you simply copy and paste [the main file](https://github.com/antarktikali/threejs-sunlight/blob/master/SunLight.js) into your own project, add `import * as THREE from "three";` at the top, then look at the console to see what errors you need to fix to run with the latest version. There will probably be quite a few. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! In this way, I could able to merge two models. The only problem now is in the SunLight script. Whatever I tried didn't work in the main script. So put it as another script and added the old version of threejs to the very beginning to run it. It imported the SunScript.js file, and now the only error I get is "three.module.js:7791 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D." Do you have any idea how to fix this?